# Circuit works in opposite way

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, sensor, proximity-sensor

I am designing a automatic sanitiser system with IR sensor. Below I have attached the circuit diagram.
[image]

But the reality is the DC Pump keeps on running and when IR detects anything the DC Pump stops. This is exactly the opposite way of behaviour. It would be helpful if I have did anything wrong, or how can I do the exact one.

Comment: That isn't a circuit diagram. It says in the picture that it's a wiring diagram. There is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using a PNP transistor that switches the high (positive) side of the load, and is switched on when the sensor output is low.  From your description you probably want an NPN transistor to switch the low (ground) side of the load; this will be switched on when the sensor output is high.  Otherwise keep the PNP and invert the sensor output using a (low power) transistor or inverter IC.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, either the current PNP transistor should be replaced with a NPN one, and have the pump connected to its collector, or drive the current PNP transistor with an additional NPN transistor as follow:

Note: Probably the resistor values must be optimized.
[image: wiring 1]

If you decide though to use only one NPN transistor, make sure it can withstand the current of the motor. Furthermore, based on your drawing, it seems that the supply consists of a 5V USB. If that is the case bear in mind that bipolar transistors have a certain collector to emitter voltage drop, which will reduce the voltage available for the pump.

#Update

The answer above would be valid only if the output of the module was active high, but apparently, according to this [schematic](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F619sYq5C-3L._SL1001_.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.de%2F-%2Fen%2FElectrely-avoidance-photoelectric-reflection-detection%2Fdp%2FB07G38MXW8&tbnid=hlUyFW1o1s8O5M&vet=12ahUKEwjN3L233a3wAhWCLOwKHWaPCMMQMygBegQIARBD..i&docid=FMnfx1g7HL-OiM&w=1001&h=1001&itg=1&q=Youmile%20Pack%20IR%20Infrared%20%20schematic&ved=2ahUKEwjN3L233a3wAhWCLOwKHWaPCMMQMygBegQIARBD), this pcb has an active low output and hence it should work the way you originally wired it. If it is still not working as expected, probably you must have misconnected the transistor, e.g. the emitter is connected to OUT, collector to the motor, and base to GND. In this configuration, the transistor behaves simply as a diode and the behavior you see should be expected.

Comment: there should be a resistor in series with the PNP's base.

Comment: https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Automatic-Alcohol-Dispenser-No-Arduino-Needed/ in this they have used the same but it is working

Comment: @INDIANDECODER I just found online a possible schematic for your pcb. Forget my previous answer. I thought, the output of your PCB was active high, but according to the schematic it seems to be active low.

Comment: @vtolentino You are correct. My sensor output was high on detection and low when not detected. The one in online is vice versa. I changed PNP to NPN and it worked

Comment: I'm glad it worked. :)